# ¿Por qué cuando compilo de .scss a .css con Sass se genera un archivo .css.map?

Tags: css, sass

estoy haciendo varios programas simples y es mi primer día utilizando Sass, estoy intentando compilar un programa .scss a .css mediante el comando en consola: `sass nesting.scss:nesting.css`.

En principio se me debería generar un archivo nesting.css el cual enlazaría a mi programa principal nesting.html. Pero cuando se compila me genera dos archivos uno llamado nesting.css, donde dentro solo encuentro esto:

```
 "/*# sourceMappingURL=nesting.css.map */
```

y otro llamado nesting.css.map el cual me muestra:

```
{
"version": 3,
"mappings": "",
"sources": [],
"names": [],
"file": "nesting.css"
}
```

Claro mi programa principal no hace los cambios de tipologíaa de texto y color que yo he generado con el documento Sass nesting.scss.

Juraría que el problema se encuentra en la compilación de Sass a Css y en la generación del archivo nesting.css.map el cual no se para que se utiliza.
Sí alguien me puediese echar una mano sería de gran ayuda para poder seguir avanzando en el uso de Sass.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, el .map es solo un archivo que identifica donde están las fuentes de tus ficheros css. se genera por defecto, es inocuo y puedes desactivar esta funcionalidad usando la opción `--no-source-map`

Comment: En cualquier caso, muestranos tu scss y el css que esperas obtener. El fichero de salida no debería estar vacío si tu archivo scss tiene contenido. ¿Has guardado el archivo fuente antes de compilar?

Comment: Hola Pablo mil gracias era eso no había guardado el fichero .scss antes de compilar, error de novato mil gracias. Igualmente gracis por explicarme el porque se genera el fichero .css.map.

Comment: hahaha le pasa a cualquiera. De nada.